# Visual Studio 2010 unable connect to MySql server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 + MySql connector 6.6.4. Connection to the local database works. But to connect to the database on the hosting does not work. Create a connection, enter - server name, user name, password . I open the combobox "Database name" - show error "unable to retrieve the list of database". When I enter the name of the database manually and click Test Connection, get error "Unable to connect to any of the specifiedMySql host". 
  In what could be the reason? Internet access on my machine via a proxy server. May need to specify a proxy in the connection string? But I can not find where.

Comment: Are you sure the hoster allows "public" access. Many limit access to databases to their local network for security reasons (while in fact it's arguable whether there's a security gain)

Answer (score 1):

On the hosting you need to add IP address are allowed to connect to database. It works.